# Clicking any hash/"#" link, even in Seven themed edit page tabs, scrolls to top of page?

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, navigation

I have a custom themed Drupal 7 site [here](http://www.spacesymposium.org). If you click on the left or right arrows in the top slide show or bottom "logo parade", the browser will scroll to that hash tag (undesired). Also, when logged in and looking at an edit page (uses Seven admin theme, not custom theme), clicking on a vertical tab e.g. "Menu settings" will scroll to the top of the page. This is disorienting and disruptive!

What's most troubling is that I can't reproduce this issue on the local test version of the site. The home page slide show and logo parade cause no scrolling when clicking around. The edit pages are a dream without unwanted scrolling...

FireBug isn't reporting anything odd. I'm not seeing noticeable differences between the live and local sites. Another Drupal 7 site I have on the same production server is not having this issue. It works great locally. I'm stumped.

This might be unrelated (maybe a related clue!), but for this site specifically I'm also having some odd ajax issues when editing views via Seven theme (and it's working great on my local version). When attempting to add a field to any view I'm getting this message, followed by the overlay instead loading as its own page:

```
An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /admin/structure/views/ajax/add-item/articles/block/field
StatusText: 
ResponseText: 
ReadyState: 4
```

Any thoughts on where I should start to troubleshoot this issue? I truly appreciate the assist in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears to be that the arrows for the slide show and "logo parade" are linked directly to their container `<div id="logo-parade">` with the anchor `href="#logo-parade"`, which causes the page to essentially "snap" to the container, since the div id is the same as anchor when called as a hash (you can see in the url that `#logo-parade` gets appended).

This could be caused because of a portion of javascript is not being called/run properly which should trigger the carousel without needing to use anchors.

Since your problem doesn't occur in development (you can test this by clicking on one of the arrows and making sure that in your URL bar you don't see `#logo-parade` appended) it leads me to believe that perhaps a file hasn't loaded correctly on the server, or perhaps the .htaccess rewrite has something to do with it

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That sounds like a great couple of places to look. If it's file related, I'm guessing it's core related as this is happening in a core admin themed edit page as well. I'll mess with .htaccess after that. More updates shortly...

Comment: So far I can confirm that my local and remote versions are identical, minus the db login info and with a couple extra lines in .htaccess (I removed those lines to test on the live site and behavior remained the same). The site works as expected on my machine. Clicking on an edit tab on the edit page scrolls to the top of the page. All behavior is odd and unchanged. Ick. :( I'm digging in server settings, not seeing any notable differences between website setup.

I'm guessing that there is still an issue with JavaScript... somehow.

Comment: Hmm.. that is indeed very strange. Are there any differences in the development/production caching that you're using, either Drupal or otherwise 3rd party? (An example being, in the Drupal performance settings, in production cases caching may be enabled at a level which is too aggressive and causes issues which can be hard to identify).

Comment: It's fixed!!!

It turned out that the HTML5 Appcache module was causing issues. It was enabled but not fully setup yet which may have been the big issue. Life is good now.

Jon, thanks for your support!